# How to extract a single value from an array

Tags: javascript, json

I am very new to JavaScript so forgive me if this is a dumb question:

I have this Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'product_prices/' + value,
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('success', data)
  }
});
```

The value "data" produces an array:

```
success [{"price":"120.00"}]
```

What I need, is to extract the value of price (the 120) and use it later in an addition.

How do I get this value out?

Comment: console.log(data.price)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test it,
You must parse `JSON` string before using it!

`var data = JSON.parse('[{"price":"120.00"}]');
var Price = data[0].price; // 120.00
//OR IF it's Single And not Array
var Price = data.price; // 120.00`

Answer (score 3):

`data` has an array of objects with a price property. Access the first object in the array and parse it's price as a number:

```
parseFloat(data[0].price);
```

Comment: what if the price is 120.25? shouldn't one rather use parseFloat()?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
var price = data[0]['price'];
```

or:

```
var price = data[0].price;
```

Either of these work like this: you are accessing the first value in your array named data, and then the field in that value named "price". Assigning it to a variable isn't necessary.

However, you would probably want to do this inside a loop, iterating over all values of data so that, in the case the first element of data isn't what you want, you can still catch it. For example:

```
data.forEach(function(i) {
    console.log(data[i].price);
    //do stuff with the value here
});
```

Comment: be sure to declare this variable within an appropriate scope for acquisition of the value later.

Answer (score 1):

Since your response is an array, access the first position, and then access the object property:

```
data[0].price; //"120.00"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {},
    sum    = 0;
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'product_prices/' + value,
    success: function (data) {
        result = data[0];
    }
});

sum = parseFloat(result.price) + 2.25;
```

Comment: The question states: "What I need, is to extract the value of price (the 120) and use it later in an addition.

How do I get this value out?" so this example, given the provided code, provides a valid example of how to "extract the value of price ... and use it in a later addition".